# Google Sheets Script - Efficient Way to Find and Replace Multiple Phrases?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm wondering if theres anyway to shorten this code. I need to find and replace a bunch of phrases with the hyperlinked version of the phrase, and I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to do it. Thank you in advance!!

```
function insertUrl() {
  let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder("Example 1")
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .ignoreDiacritics(true)
    .findAll();
  ranges.forEach(function(range){
    range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("https://www.website1.com/","Example 1")');
    }
    );
  {
  let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder("Example 1")
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .ignoreDiacritics(true)
    .findAll();
  ranges.forEach(function(range){
    range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("https://www.website2.com/","Example 1")');
    }
    );
}
  {
  let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder("Example 3")
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .ignoreDiacritics(true)
    .findAll();
  ranges.forEach(function(range){
    range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("https://www.website3.com/","Example 3")');
    }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that takes in the URL and the text to find as parameters.

```
function insertUrl(text, url) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .createTextFinder(text)
        .matchEntireCell(true)
        .matchCase(true)
        .matchFormulaText(false)
        .ignoreDiacritics(true)
        .findAll()
        .forEach(function (range) {
            range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK(' + url + ',"' + text + '")');
        });
}
insertUrl("Example 1", "https://www.website1.com/");
insertUrl("Example 1", "https://www.website2.com/");
insertUrl("Example 3", "https://www.website3.com/");
```

Was your use of `Example 1` with `website2.com` a typo? You probably meant to use `Example 2` there instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please confirm the value of `ar`. If your actual situation is different from the sample value, please modify them.

```js
function insertUrl() {
  // Please set the text and the formula you want to use.
  const ar = [
    { text: "Example 1", formula: '=HYPERLINK("https://www.website1.com/","Example 1")' },
    { text: "Example 1", formula: '=HYPERLINK("https://www.website2.com/","Example 1")' },
    { text: "Example 3", formula: '=HYPERLINK("https://www.website3.com/","Example 3")' },
  ];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ar.forEach(({ text, formula }) =>
    ss.createTextFinder(text)
      .matchEntireCell(true)
      .matchCase(true)
      .matchFormulaText(false)
      .ignoreDiacritics(true)
      .replaceAllWith(formula)
  );
}
```

- In this modification, an array including the values you want to replace is created. And, the formula is put using `replaceAllWith`. By this, I thought that the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.
- As another direction for reducing the process cost of your script, you can also use Sheets API as follows. In this case, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

  ```
    function insertUrl() {
      // Please set the text and the formula you want to use.
      const ar = [
        { text: "Example 1", formula: '=HYPERLINK("https://www.website1.com/","Example 1")' },
        { text: "Example 1", formula: '=HYPERLINK("https://www.website2.com/","Example 1")' },
        { text: "Example 3", formula: '=HYPERLINK("https://www.website3.com/","Example 3")' },
      ];
      const requests = ar.map(({ text, formula }) => ({ findReplace: { allSheets: true, find: text, replacement: formula, matchEntireCell: true, matchCase: true } }));
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId());
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [replaceAllWith(replaceText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceallwithreplacetext)

Answer (score 0):

Try and use literal notation

```
`=HYPERLINK("${url}","${text}")`
```

script

```
function insertURL() {
  const changes = {
    'qwant': "https://www.qwant.com/",
    'google': "https://www.google.com/",
  };
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const requests = Object.entries(changes).map(([text, url]) => ({
    findReplace: {
      find: text,
      replacement: `=HYPERLINK("${url}","${text}")`,
      matchEntireCell: true,
      allSheets: true,
    },
  }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

enable **google sheets api** service

[batchupdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate)

[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)