# Is nesting possible in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For the first time ever in my lessons, I saw a completely different way of writing javascript code:

```
let parentClicks = 0;
let childClicks = 0;

document
  .getElementById("parent")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
  document
    .getElementById("parent-count")
    .innerText = (++parentClicks) + '';
});

document
  .getElementById("child")
  .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  document
    .getElementById("child-count")
    .innerText = (++childClicks) + '';
});
```

I was used to seeing nesting on HTML/CSS, but it's the first time ever I see it on JS.

Do these points mean this or they have a complete different meaning?

```
document.getElementById("parent")
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("parent-count")
  document.innerText = (++parentClicks) + '';
});

document.getElementById("child")
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  document.getElementById("child-count")
  document.innerText = (++childClicks) + '';
});
```

Comment: there's nothing "nested" here

Comment: But there is 'chaining'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is very permissive about whitespace. For some sorts of syntactical constructs, putting a newline between them is the same as if there was no newline there. (It's possible to write any JavaScript on only a single line of code, after all - it's just that that's unreadable)

This:

```
document
  .getElementById("parent")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
  document
    .getElementById("parent-count")
    .innerText = (++parentClicks) + '';
});
```

is equivalent to

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("parent-count").innerText = (++parentClicks) + '';
});
```

It's not the same as your `document.addEventListener("click", function() {` because your code adds a click listener to the document, not to the parent.

Where one decides to put newlines is often a purely stylistic choice, usually in an effort to make the code easier to understand at a glance. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71231960), one may well prefer to do this

```
let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder("Example 1")
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .ignoreDiacritics(true)
    .findAll();
```

instead of

```
let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().createTextFinder("Example 1").matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).matchFormulaText(false).ignoreDiacritics(true).findAll();
```

even though they mean the exact same thing.

Comment: It's not the newlines that are operative though, its the `.`. Possibly useful to touch on chaining for the OP.

Comment: @Neo78 Sure, but you also need a `})` at the end

Answer (score 1):

The indentation looks off in your first example. A few editor might throw error for this. It's always best to use period together in such scenarios. For ex- document. and not document
.